# Fire events manually

Tags: c#

I have some controls on my form to which I assigned (via designer) functions to the Leave envent, something like this:

```
textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(f1);
textBox2.Leave += new System.EventHandler(f2);
textBox3.Leave += new System.EventHandler(f3);
```

These functions perform some validation on the textboxes. **Note that not all the textboxes call the same delegate.**

What I need now is to be able to tell them "hey, fire the Leave event" when I want. On my case I call this function somewhere at start:

```
private void validateTextBoxes()
{
    foreach (Control c in c.Controls)
    {
        TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            // Fire the tb.Leave event to check values
        }
    }
}
```

So every textbox validates with its own code.

Comment: `if(TB.Leave != null) { TB.Leave(this, new EventArgs()); }`?

Comment: [If this is `Windows Forms` validation has already been done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx).

Comment: Gavin: The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Leave' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: If ***manually*** means fire them by yourself, you have done it. What are you asking for?

Comment: Ken Kin: where did I do that? VS Designer assigns what function should be called when the event is fired but the event is NEVER fired unless you edit (at runtime) a textbox and leave it.

Answer (score 5):

I presume you dont *really* want to fire the Leave event you just want to validate the textbox in the same way the leave event would, why not just run them both through the same validation method..

```
private void ValidateTextBox(TextBox textBox)
{
    //Validate your textbox here..
}

private void TextBox_Leave(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textbox !=null)
    {
        ValidateTextBox(textbox);
    } 
}
```

then wire up the leave event

```
textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(TextBox_Leave);
textBox2.Leave += new System.EventHandler(TextBox_Leave);
textBox3.Leave += new System.EventHandler(TextBox_Leave);
```

then your initial validation code.

```
private void validateTextBoxes()
{
    foreach (Control c in c.Controls)
    {
        TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            // No need to fire leave event 
            //just call ValidateTextBox with our textbox
            ValidateTextBox(tb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is how to know what validation method is assigned to what textbox, since they can be different.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to your current approach, you might want to consider using the [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event instead, which is precisely for this kind of thing.

If you use [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx), you can then use [ContainerControl.ValidateChildren()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158374.aspx) to perform the validation logic for all the child controls. Note that the Form class implements ValidateChildren().

Personally, I think that's what you should be doing.

Comment: Chosing a place where to validate doesn't solve the problem on how to call the Leave methods

Comment: It is not a place but a way. You are reinventing the wheel and you are bound to fall in all the traps `leave` has to offer (inability to skip validation, need to resort to reflection to be able to call OnXXXXX event handlers) which [Windows forms validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx) already handles.